# Emacs line numbers auto load

Tags: emacs

This is my [.emacs](https://gist.github.com/4482483) . Still it does not load the line numbers on opening. I need to "M-x linum-mode" to enable such option. any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to start Emacs with debug mode enabled? emacs --debug-init

Comment: I would add for particular type of file. Not every type require linum-mode.  Also in emacs, you can do lots of thing without line numbers, incluing viewing compiling error.

Comment: Open any file not only Emacs...

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
(require 'linum)              ;; you miss this line
(global-linum-mode 1)
```

Eventually you could check [another way to enable Linum](http://www.emacswiki.org/LineNumbers).

Comment: @Benoit: `global-linum-mode` is auto-loaded, so the `require` is superfluous.

Comment: @Stefan: what you say makes sense, but I got a `symbol's definition is void` if I remove the `require` line...

Comment: @Benoit: then I guess you're using an old Emacs.

Comment: First line is not required

Answer (score 2):

Could it be you have a bug in your `.emacs` before the call to enable linum-mode?  E.g. the `load` of Tuareg-mode looks suspicious because the file name you provide seems to point to a directory rather than a file.  IOW, check your `*Messages*` buffer, and/or try to remove everything but `(global-linum-mode 1)` from your .emacs.

Comment: what is *Messages* buffer?

Comment: Correct analysis. The error in these lines:                   (autoload 'typerex-mode "typerex" "Major mode for editing Caml code" t)
(load "/home/moataz/Downloads/tuareg-2.0.6")                                                                                                        any idea why?

Comment: the documentation says Add the following line near the beginning of your ~/.emacs file: (load "/where/ever/you/put/tuareg-mode/tuareg-site-file". so what is this tuareg-site-file?